# Sinch Registration failed iOS SDK when create client making call

Tags: ios, swift, sinch

Registration failed: Error(code: 1, domain: generic, message: The operation couldn’t be completed. (VideoCallKitSwift.JWTError error 0.))

```
self.client = try SinchRTC.client(withApplicationKey: APPLICATION_KEY,
                                        environmentHost: ENVIRONMENT_HOST,
                                        userId: userId)
```

Can please someone have the solution why I'm getting this error.